Compute time-to-next-warmest-day in Haskell without using a conversion to-or-from `Data.Map`
Consider the following problem:

Given an array of integers temperatures represents the daily temperatures, return an array answer such that answer[i] is the number of days you have to wait after the ith day to get a warmer temperature. If there is no future day for which this is possible, keep answer[i] == 0 instead.

I've solved this several different ways, which you can see below:
  warmer :: [Int] -> [Int]
  warmer = M.elems . go [] . zip [0..]
    where
      go stack [] = foldr ((`M.insert` 0) . fst) M.empty stack
      go [] ((i,x):rest) = go [(i,x)] rest
      go ((j,y):stack) ((i,x):rest)
        | x > y     = M.insert j (i-j) (go stack ((i,x):rest))
        | otherwise = go ((i,x):(j,y):stack) rest

warmer' :: Vector Int -> Vector Int
warmer' xs = snd $ V.ifoldl' go ([], V.replicate (V.length xs) 0) xs
  where
    go ([]         , ys) i x = ([(i,x)], ys)
    go ((j,y):stack, ys) i x
      | x > y     = go (stack, ys // [(j,i-j)]) i x
      | otherwise = ((i,x):(j,y):stack, ys)

warmer'' :: Vector Int -> [Int]
warmer'' xs = M.elems $ snd $ V.ifoldl' go ([], M.fromAscList $ zip [0..] $ zipWith const [0,0..] (V.toList xs)) xs
  where
    go ([]         , days) i x = ([(i,x)], days)
    go ((j,y):stack, days) i x
      | x > y     = go (stack, M.insert j (i-j) days) i x
      | otherwise = ((i,x):(j,y):stack, days)

All of these feel unwieldy because they use clumsy tricks (like using a Map and then converting to a list) to get around the need to perform random-access writes into the output. More generally, I have noticed that algorithms that require O(1) random-access to elements in an array/list are always a bit awkward in a purely functional language.
What I would really like to ask is, "how should I do this if I want it to be fast, concise, and 'simple-looking'?" But that's clearly opinion-based, and is not a very interesting question besides.

To make this more precise, I will ask:  Is there a way to solve this with the type [Int] -> [Int] in O(n log n) that avoids the need for random-access writes and all the awkwardness it entails?

This question is I suppose the next in a long series in which I have attempted to explore the extent to which we can escape the need to perform index arithmetic when we want to implement fast algorithms in Haskell.
P.S.: I would also be interested to hear if there is a more appropriate location for such questions, e.g. another stack exchange site, a Haskell IRC community, etc.

A comment on the other answer says "Maybe it's possible to do something with a fancy... stack to keep track of what numbers you are searching for and how far back they were.". I present here an instantiation of that idea. Our stack is going to alternate between values that we don't know the answer for and sequences of answers we do know. As in the other answer, I need lists that store their length.
import Data.List
import Data.Monoid

type LWL a = ([a], Sum Int)

singleton :: a -> LWL a
singleton a = ([a], 1)

len :: LWL a -> Int
len = getSum . snd

One way to represent a stack that alternates between two different types is to have a list of tuples.
type Stack = [(Int, LWL Int)]

The first half of the tuple will be a temperature where we're still waiting for a warmer day; the second half is the answers for days earlier than that. When we push onto the stack, it will be convenient to have not just a new temperature to push, but also a pending list of answers we've learned because we're pushing that temperature. That pending list will be the first argument.
push :: LWL Int -> Stack -> Int -> Stack
push pre stack n = case stack of
    [] -> [(n, pre)]
    (m,is):rest | n <= m -> (n, pre) : stack
                | otherwise -> push (is <> singleton (1 + len pre) <> pre) rest n

The only thing left to do is finalize the stack, inserting 0s for each pending search.
warmer :: [Int] -> [Int]
warmer = foldMap (\(_, is) -> 0:fst is) . foldl' (push mempty) mempty


I believe this can be done in O(n).  The idea is to combine searching
for the next higher temperature with solving the part of the problem
up until that temperature occurs.
So for example if we have [10, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12] we will see 10 and
while searching for the higher value 11 we will produce the answer for
3, 4, 5.  Notice that the next temperatures for these can't be past
the 11 - we know these numbers must all be less than or equal to 10.
We use lists with lengths:
data ListWithLength = LWL { list :: [Int], len :: Int }

emptyLWL :: ListWithLength
emptyLWL = LWL [] 0

cons :: Int -> ListWithLength -> ListWithLength
cons x (LWL xs n) = LWL (x:xs) (1+n)

append :: ListWithLength -> ListWithLength -> ListWithLength
append (LWL xs m) (LWL ys n) = LWL (xs ++ ys) (m + n)

The doPrefix function takes a limit and an input list. It returns
the solution for a prefix (with length), and the remaining unsolved
part.  This unsolved part will begin with the first number greater
than the limit, or be empty if none was found.
doPrefix :: Int -> [Int] -> (ListWithLength, [Int])
doPrefix lim [] = (emptyLWL, [])
doPrefix lim (x:xs)
    | x > lim = (emptyLWL, x:xs)
    | otherwise =
        case doPrefix x xs of
            (ys, []) -> (0 `cons` ys, [])
            (ys, rest) ->
              ((len ys + 1) `cons` ys `append` zs, rest')
              where
                (zs, rest') = doPrefix lim rest

Now just passing maxBound as the limit will solve for the whole list.
solve :: [Int] -> [Int]
solve = list . fst . doPrefix maxBound


I believe you can accomplish the same thing with Seq Int.

Do you know if it can be done with a single recursive call, instead of two?

@lanf I don't see an obvious way at the moment. Maybe it's possible to do something with a fancy (tree-structured?) stack to keep track of what numbers you are searching for and how far back they were.
